# while trying to put JSONObject into JsonArray Override the JsonObject in for loop condition

Tags: java, json

My `jsonobject` given below

```
{
      "TopLevelDomainList": {
        "TopLevelId": "01",
        "DomainName": "List of Domains for e-Governance",
        "APIVersion": "1.0",
        "ListVersion": "1.1",
        "ListVersionDate": "1/10/2015 12:30:50",
        "Banner": {
          "Image": "http://localhost/image/logo.jpg"
        },
        "Footer": {
          "Image": "http://localhost/image/footer.jpg"
        },
        "ParticipatingDomains": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "DomainName": "toplevel1",
            "Location": "http://toplevel.com",
            "Icon": "http://toplevel.com"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "DomainName": "toplevel2",
            "Location": "http://toplevel.com",
            "Icon": "http://toplevel.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Am writing java code here What  i want is  ss or

```
ja =[{id:1,name:toplevel},{id:2,name:toplevel2}]




   JSONObject objj = firstSport.getJSONObject("TopLevelDomainList"); 
        String ob = objj.getString("TopLevelId"); 
        System.out.println("ob is !!!=>"+ob);

                    if(firstSport.has("TopLevelDomainList"))
                    {
                       count=1;                                
                       obj1 = objj.getJSONArray("ParticipatingDomains"); 

                        System.out.println("obj value is ===>"+obj1.length());


                        for (int i = obj1.length()-1; i >=0; i--) {

                            JSONObject rec = obj1.getJSONObject(i);
                             Id = rec.getString("Id");
                             System.out.println("id is !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+Id);
                            Name = rec.getString("DomainName");
                            banobj.put("Id", Id);
                            banobj.put("DomainName", Name);
                            banobj.put("HasChildren", "true");
                            ja.put(banobj);

                            System.out.println("ja is ===> "+ja);
                            System.out.println("banobj1 value is !!!!"+banobj);


                        }               

                    ss=ja.toString();
                    System.out.println("ss is ===> "+ss);
```

now am getting ja or ss value is
 `[{id:2,name:toplevel2},{id:2,name:toplevel2}]`
if am trying the reverse for loop also am getting value same like ja array 1 instead of 2;

Comment: did you try using using a debugger?
your code does not compile.  Id, Namem ja, banobj are not defined anywhere, please use proper naming for variables and tell us what the type is.  
It is easier for us to tell you what is wrong if you return he full output of your program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using **the same** banobj (the same reference) for every element that you are trying to put into array, so you just **ovveride** its values in cycle.

Try using something like

```
  banobj.put("Id", Id);
  banobj.put("DomainName", Name);
  banobj.put("HasChildren", "true");
  ja.put(banobj);
  banobj = new BanObj(); // I don't know what should be here exaclty
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, So I need to add the elements, if am put the data its override the existing data. Now am using JsronArrayBuilder and JsonObjectBuilder to add the elements. its working properly.
JsonArrayBuilder builder1 = Json.createArrayBuilder();
           JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();

```
                for(int i=0;i<obj1.length();i++){
                    JSONObject rec = obj1.getJSONObject(i);
                     Id = rec.getString("Id");
                    Name = rec.getString("DomainName");
                           builder.add("Id",Id)
                            .add("DomainName", Name)
                            .add("HasChildren", "true");
                    builder1.add(builder);      

                }     empObj=builder1.build();


                ss=empObj.toString();
```